# Laravel 5.2 Auth::login($user) not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am writing a Laravel 5.2 application. I need to manually login the user for which I am using `\Auth::login($user)`. I am doing it in following way.

```
  if ($user = User::where('phone',session('phone'))->first())
  {
        \Auth::login($user);

        //   \Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        //  Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => 'password']);

        $data = \Auth::user();  //returning correct results
  }
```

I have tried all the options namely `Auth::login($user)`, `Authh:loginUsingId($user->id)` and `attempt` method. These methods are working fine as the $data variable is storing the object of correct user. But the problem is when I move to other route say `'/home'` the user remain no more authenticated.

**What might be the wrong here? How could I do it correctly?**

Comment: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/temporary-user-switching I tried this link, works very well :) let me know if it helps!

Comment: no, it isn't helpful here. Because I have implemented the quite same thing from different point of view. I am getting the problem in persistence of authentication.

Comment: What is your route setup? Does your `/home` route implement `web` and `auth` middlewares?

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 5.2, you have to attach all your routes that need session with [the 'web' middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups). See your app/Http/Kernel.php, the 'web' middleware contains the \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.

Answer (score 0):

In routes you have to use web in laravel 5.2

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/profile', 'HomeController@profile');
});
```